# Couldnt deploy repo to GitHub pages

Tags: node.js, github, npm, github-pages

I switched my acc to github student and linked namecheap domain. And created personal portfolio repo with named [hedevelope.github.io](https://github.com/hedevelope/hedevelope.github.io) and it redirects to my domain name which is hedevelope.me but there is an error "Site not found".
[Website error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hh2co.png)

Where is the problem i couldnt figure. Because i looked deployment logs on github pages but there is no problem. Vercel couldnt deploy too but netlify deploys correctly in a minute.
[This is error before version change on package.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uk4RM.png) and
[After adding npm versions to package.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3M4eW.png)

I couldnt run project locally because it gives too much errors and i solved with downgrade the node version. And added it to package.json to github understands and runs with that versions. But same result page doesnt found.

Note: i used the same files that the owner published. credits:https://github.com/bchiang7/v4
My project on netlify: https://bespoke-cuchufli-f038f1.netlify.app/
package.json code that i add

```json
"engines" : { 
  "npm" : "14.16.0",
  "node" : "6.14.11"
}
```

Comment: i just temporary point custom domain on netlify while i get this solution.

Comment: Did you read the full documentation? Check this out https://docs.github.com/en/pages/getting-started-with-github-pages/configuring-a-publishing-source-for-your-github-pages-site